# How can I find the name and profile photo of the creator of a discord server in node.js? in v14

Tags: discord.js

I want to opt in to the username, and profile picture of the creator of a discord server, any ideas on how to do that?

i just want the username for a info command, and the profile pic for an embed

i try usin

```
message.guild.owner.username
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the owner of a guild, you can use [`Guild#fetchOwner()`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchOwner). Note this a promise which needs to be properly resolved. You can then access the user with [`GuildMember#user`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=user) which then has the properties and methods you want

```js
const owner = await message.guild.fetchOwner()
const username = owner.user.username
const userAvatarURL = owner.user.displayAvatarURL()
```

If you also would like to account for guild avatars, you can simply use [`GuildMember#displayAvatarURL()`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=displayAvatarURL)

```js
const avatarURL = owner.displayAvatarURL()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Guild documentation](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/14.14.1/class/Guild) for the latest version, `Guild` does not have a `owner` property. It does however have `ownerId`.

With that in mind, you should be able to look for the owner's `GuildMember` object by looking through the guild's members.

```js
const owner = message.guild.members.cache.get(message.guild.ownerId);
```

or

```js
const owner = await message.guild.members.fetch(message.guild.ownerId);
```

---

You can then access the information you want with:

```js
const username = owner.displayName || owner.user.username;
const profilePhoto = owner.user.displayAvatarURL();
```

Keep in mind that a user's name and image (if they have Nitro) may be different in one guild than another.

Comment: uhhh, for me, the console says:  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'displayAvatarURL')